# Complex solutions to ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, complex

How do I solve the following IVP problem in Mathematica so that I get real solutions?

$Q'(t)=b - \dfrac{Q(t)}{100-t}; \quad Q(0)=250$

I tried the following:

$\text{$\$$Assumptions}=b>0;\text{$\$$Assumptions}=t>0;$

$f=\text{DSolve}\left[\left\{Q'(t)=b-\frac{Q(t)}{100-t},Q(0)=250\right\},Q,t\right][[1,1,2]]$

$f(t)$

which results in the following:

$\frac{1}{2} (-2 i \pi  b t-2 b t \log (100)-200 b \log (t-100)+2 b t \log (t-100)+200 i \pi  b+200 b \log (100)-5 t+500)$

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you read my answer before having accepted the Nasser's one?

Comment: It works fine if you add `$Assumptions = t <100` before your `DSolve`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get complex solution, depending on your initial condition !

First solve without setting IC

```
ode = q'[t] == b - q[t]/(100 - t);
ic = q[0] == 250;
sol = q[t] /. First@DSolve[ode, q[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above is your solution `q(t)`. It is all nice and no complex numbers. But you want the above to be `250` when `t=0`, so

```
myConstant =C[1]/. First@Solve[(sol/.t->0)==0,C[1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(sol/.C[1]->myConstant)//Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the complex solution comes from your initial conditions requirements at `t=0`. If you change initial conditions to something else, the solution is not complex. Push the time to over `100`

```
ode=q'[t]==b- q[t]/(100-t);
ic=q[0]==250;
sol=q[t]/.First@DSolve[{ode,q[101]==250},q[t],t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now the solution is real. So it depends on where you set the initial condition at and the complex solution comes from solving for constant of integration.

Comment: Nasser, when I do the problem by hnad, I get the following:

Comment: Nasser, when I do the problem by hand, I get the following:$-b(100-t)ln|100-t|+C(100-t)$ which results in $C = 2.5+b ln100$.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is as follows.

```
$Assumptions = b > 0; $Assumptions = t >= 0;
DSolve[{Q'[t] == b \[Minus] Q[t]/(100 \[Minus] t), Q[0] == 250}, Q[t], t]
```

> {{Q[t] -> 
>      1/2 (500 + 200 I b [Pi] - 5 t - 2 I b [Pi] t + 200 b Log[100] - 
>         2 b t Log[100] - 200 b Log[-100 + t] + 2 b t Log[-100 + t])}}

```
 FullSimplify[1/2 (500 + 200 I b \[Pi] - 5 t - 2 I b \[Pi] t + 200 b Log[100] - 
2 b t Log[100] - 200 b Log[-100 + t] + 2 b t Log[-100 + t]),Assumptions->b > 0&& t> 0 && t <= 100]
```

> -(1/2) (-100 + t) (5 + b Log[10000] - 2 b Log[100 - t])